# How to save matplotlib figure to jpeg file from javascript request?

Tags: javascript, matplotlib, save

I'm developing a web application in linux environnement to display image of data array.
So i would like to save images from python plot to jpeg files to be able to display them in a browser. Python code works correctly when executed from the console. But if called with a javascript request it hangs due to plt use, even with pltioff(). done message is send if i remove all plt code.

python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import json

curr = os.getcwd()
plt.ioff()

fig, ax  = plt.subplots( 1 ) 
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
fig.savefig(curr+"/"+'test.jpeg',dpi=224,quality=50)

messJ = json.dumps( "done" )
print('Content-type: text/html')
print("\n")
print "%s" %messJ
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <title>my page</title>
    </head>

    <body >
<input   type="button" id="plotsrv" value="plotsrv"  />
    </body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pythonplot.js"></script>
```

javascript :

```
document.getElementById('plotsrv').addEventListener('click', trait_Vdatasrv, false);

function trait_Vdatasrv (e) {

var url = 'pyplot.py';
console.log("url:"+url);
            $.post(url,{ file:'ncfile' }, function(data){

                $('#data').html(data);
                console.log("data"+data);
                var jsdec=JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(jsdec);     }
            );     }
```

Regards

Comment: Could you tell some about the environment you are working with? What handles the request from JavaScript and runs this Python script?

Comment: ok i added explanations

Comment: No, you have not.

Comment: @ johanL , thanks for this very usefull participation

Comment: It might be (looking in my crystal ball)  a permissions issue. The web-server used tries to save the image to a location which it is not allowed to. Check the error logs of the used web-server if possible.

Comment: thanks but no, the plot line alone is enough to hang. error returned is    The server encountered an internal error and was 
    unable to complete your request.     Error 500 message:    End of script output before headers:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found , 
it is needed to add matplotlib.use('Agg')
to avoid display output